# How to compare list and return match and non match in python?

Tags: python, list

how to compare the 2 list of same length and return the matches and non matches elements have to append as a single element with space

```
l1=["a","b","c"]
l2=["a","d","c"]

result=[]
for i in l1:
    for j in l2:
        if i == j:
            match = i
            result.append(match)
        else:
            non_match = i + " "+ j
            result.append(non_match)

print(result)

Actual Output:
['a', 'a d', 'a c', 'b a', 'b d', 'b c', 'c a', 'c d', 'c']

Expected Output:
["a","b d","c"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other answers tell other methods, but I solve your issue. The issue with you code is because you are running through the python list completely two times. You can use zip function from python here. I have solved your code for you.

```
l1=["a","b","c"]
l2=["a","d","c"]

result=[]
for i,j in zip(l1, l2):
    if i == j:
        match = i
        result.append(match)
    else:
        non_match = i + " "+ j
        result.append(non_match)

print(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

As long as order of the items in the output doesn't matter, you could do this:

```
Output = list(map(lambda x: " ".join(set(x)), zip(List1, List2)))

>>> Output
['a', 'd b', 'c']
```

The logic can be broken down at follows:

1: `zip` the two lists together:

```
# display the zipped lists:
>>> list(zip(List1, List2))
[('a', 'a'), ('b', 'd'), ('c', 'c')]
```

2: Turn each tuple in the resulting list into a set (to get unique values):

```
# display the result of calling set on the zipped lists
>>> list(map(set, zip(List1, List2)))
[{'a'}, {'d', 'b'}, {'c'}]
```

3: concatenate the members of each set with `join`

```
Output = list(map(lambda x: " ".join(set(x)), zip(List1, List2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through both lists, appending a space & the List2 element if the corresponding elements are not equal to each other.

```
[List1[i] + (f" {List2[i]}" if List1[i] != List2[i] else '') for i in range(len(List1))]
```

I'll add @grind's answer as well for completeness. I think we both like it a bit better. As mentioned it doesn't need indexes and the formatting also includes the concatenation of left & right which I consider an improvement too.

```
[left if left == right else f'{left} {right'} for left, right in zip(List1, List2)]
```

The first one will throw an IndexError if the lengths of the two lists are different. The second will result in a new list which has a length equal to the shorter of the two input lists.

Comment: This is prone to `IndexErrors` if `List1` is longer than `List2`. `for i in range(len(...))` is generally an antipattern in Python.

Comment: Agreed but the problem does state the lists are the same length.

Comment: Why not `[left if left == right else f'{left} {right'} for left, right in zip(List1, List2)]`? No need to screw around with indices.

Comment: Yes, I like that fine. When list lengths are different it behaves differently (yields the shorter of the two) but the same logic applies as that behavior isn't defined by the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
[' '.join((a, b)) if a != b else a
 for a, b in zip(l1, l2)]
```

`zip(l1, l2)` can let you iterate `l1, l2` simultaneously, `''.join((a, b)) if a != b else a` is a `Conditional Expression` which expresses what you want. `Conditional Expression` part can be evaluated to value, which will eventually aggregate into the result you want through the list comprehension.

Comment: @L.F. okay. I will add some.